# Alignment Issues In IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm having some frustrating alignment issues. I had previously posted a question because everything was arranged correctly in all of the browsers except FF. I now have everything correct but of course IE has swooped in to cause problems. It works fine in IE8 and IE9 but NOT in IE7.

http://jsfiddle.net/cSq6W/2/

Basically the left column is where the right column should be and the right column is below. I have a feeling it has something to do with inline:block or display:table-cell . Are there any known bugs with these styles in IE7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display:table-cell` is not working IE7. If you desperately need functionality that can only be provided by `display: table-cell` in IE7, you have two choices:

- Use a real `<table>` and suffer unsemantic HTML.
- Use JavaScript for IE7 (and lower) to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. What I ended up doing was kinda similar. I used <!--[if lte IE 7]> for the relevant areas. I only used that because it was solely IE7 that was the problem and it was only the one page (I know this shouldn't be a widespread fix but it was very contained so I thought I should use it here).

Answer (score 1):

IE 7 specific bugs from quirksmode.org:

http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/explorer_7/index.html